# Check date format in DateTimePicker?

Tags: kendo-ui

Here issue is while enter the date in datertimepicker manually  has to display the meesage that "enter in date format" how to check the that is in programmatically.

[My fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5bchz/95/)

code:

```
function getFormattedDate(date) {
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(2);
return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you make your input for both the datatimepicker readonly that way user have to select date from datatimepicker.

Comment: ya thank you for suggestion can please check it where it is wrong i used below code :$(".datepicker-readonly").attr("readonly", "readonly");    http://jsfiddle.net/5bchz/97/

Comment: In your html code directly use <input readonly='true' name='startdatetimepicker'/>

Comment: ya thank you so much for it, i had one more issue can please help me if you dont mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871357/check-date-format-in-datetimepicker/15872263?noredirect=1#comment22595597_15872263

Comment: which issue? You can ask me.

Comment: hi Rohit i had one issue for this readonly=true this is not working in ubuntu operating system?  when i applied true for the datapickers it will be disabled their not working after clicking on them also.